# Querying email addresses other than the primary in Active Directory

Tags: sql, email, active-directory

I'm trying to query Active Directory from a stored procedure using OPENQUERY and add the values to a temporary table.  I've got everything working, except when I add the 'proxyAddresses' field to my query, it throws this error:

"OLE DB error trace [OLE/DB Provider 'ADSDSOOBject' IRowset::GetData returned 0x80040e21:  Data status returned from the provider: [COLUMN_NAME=proxyAddresses STATUS=DBSTATUS_E_CANTCONVERTVALUE]].
Msg 7346, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Could not get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider 'ADSDSOOBject'. Could not convert the data value due to reasons other than sign mismatch or overflow."

Has anyone ever had experience with querying the 'ProxyAddresses' property from SQL?  I think I read somewhere that it was returned as an array.  Maybe that's the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I guess the problem here is that proxyAddresses can be multi-valued (i.e. contains multiple values) and I suspect OPENQUERY in SQL Server can't deal with that. Not sure if there's anything you can do to get this to work, really.

Found this in an [article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/HybridADSQLTabledatasourc.aspx) which seems to confirm your and my suspicion:

> **Limits**
>
> Unfortunately, there are some Active
>   Directory values that can’t be read
>   with the ADSI linked servers. Those
>   values are called “Array Values”.
>   Array values in the Active Directory
>   are fields that allow to insert
>   unlimited multiple values. For
>   example, if you store multiple phone
>   numbers in the Active Directory
>   General tab under “Telephone
>   numbers/Other…”, you won’t be able to
>   read those via ADSI into your SQL
>   Server.

Can you skip that and query for those addresses in C# ? I could show you a sample of that.

Marc

**UPDATE**:
OK, here's the update with the method to grab a multi-valued attribute into a list of strings (assuming you already have a `DirectoryEntry` that represents that user):

```
public List<string> GetMultiValues(DirectoryEntry entry, string propertyName)
{
  if(entry == null)
  {
     return null;
  }

  List<string> results = new List<string>();

  if (entry.Properties.Contains(propertyName))
  {
     foreach (object propertValue in entry.Properties[propertyName])
     {
        results.Add(propertValue.ToString());
     }
  }

  return results;
}
```

You can now called this function like this:

```
List<string> proxyAddresses = GetMultiValues(userEntry, "proxyAddresses");
```

Comment: Yeah.  I think I'm gonna have to do it in C#.  COuld you post that sample please?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to CAST the `proxyAddresses` field manually in your `OPENQUERY` statement?